# How can I customize my Google Checkout pages to use my logo?

Tags: google-checkout

I want to customize my google checkout pages in my website like [this site](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/). I want to place my website logo in google checkout cart section. [Example](https://checkout.google.com/view/buy?o=shoppingcart&shoppingcart=966330776082367). How is this accomplished?

Comment: Did you ever find out how the bhphotvideo.com checkout was skinned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either [customize only the UI](http://sites.google.com/site/checkoutshoppingcart/customising-cart-s-ui), or get deeper into things and [customize the cart](http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=8671) itself via the API.

Comment: I dont see any css modifications that you could apply using the links provided.

Answer (score 1):

Customizing the CSS of the order pages is a feature no longer offered by Google.

For more information see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639795/how-to-customize-google-checkout/6334207#6334207) to a related question.