# How can I customize the appearance of Google Checkout?

Tags: google-checkout

I opened a merchant account with google checkout and would like to customize the html/css. I have googled and searched around, but could not find anything. It seems that its not possible at all. The merchant account doesn't show any options either. But, I found the following page, which uses a custom header:

https://checkout.google.com/view/buy?o=shoppingcart&shoppingcart=966330776082367

It seems that this page is using a custom skin, which is hosted on the google servers, however as said there is no option at all in my merchant account. If anybody knows how this can be done, please share.

**Update 1**: After searching around for hours, I found the support link, which does allow you to upload an image for the merchant account. However there is no sign of a custom css. Here is the link: http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/request.py?ctx=cm

**Update 2**: The logo I added in update 1, does not appear yet in my checkout page. I guess it needs to be approved by google first.

Answer (score 2):

Customizing the CSS of the order pages is a feature no longer offered by Google.

Regarding the custom logo see this threads for more info:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/checkout-merchants/thread?tid=607a1b33062a25a8&hl=en

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/checkout-merchants/thread?tid=3b2ae69383678515&hl=en

Note that you can customize the behavior and appearance of the shopping cart through CSS and JavaScript:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Shopping_Cart_Understanding_Shopping_Cart_Widget.html

http://sites.google.com/site/checkoutshoppingcart/customising-cart-s-ui

http://sites.google.com/site/checkoutshoppingcart/javascript-api